# Wordpress Include Header doesnt include mobile header

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made a custom .php file for my wordpress website and simply put

at the top and everything works fine, except for the fact that it doesnt include the mobile collapsable header (the normal header works). 

When i minimize firefox to under 700px it shows the mobile header graphics but it doesnt include the actual  that expands when you press the menu button.


On all the other parts of the website the header works, altho i havn't done them by hand. 
Anyone had this problem before? 
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Links to HTML code: 
V "the one that has a problem with its mobile header" 
http://waxholmspartiet.se/nyhetsflode-2/ 
--- 
V "for comparision reasons" 
http://waxholmspartiet.se/ 
--- 
If you inspect the "mobile_menu_bar mobile_menu_bar_toggle" class (the blue lines thingy that you actual click to open the menu) at both you'll see the  list for the links only exists on one of those pages.

 ---- 
this is the part i include the header at the top of my .php file where i have like 700 other rows of code for the page (about 300 of them are php).

Comment: Can you post some code, or link to some code perhaps? Also, does the mobile header sit in another file, or is it contained in the header file with the regular one?

Comment: Wait a sec, stackkoverflock thinks hes being funny by screwing up my spacing and stuff. Ima make it readable in 5 mins again...

Comment: read this if you wanna se what i wrote but in a pretty form, im gonna just ignore this problem tho cuz its wierd :D -> http://imgur.com/ZMFa5ot

Comment: Check the console to see if you got any errors